# Community♦ user suffering from Dissociative Identity Disorder

Tags: support, community-user, deleted-users

Looking at this [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3955096/revisions), I see that our hard-working friend [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) thoughtfully suggested an edit to a popular answer. Clicking through to the [Review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1051004) for the edit, though, I see that she then voted to reject her own edit as 'too minor'. This is clearly unreasonable behaviour; should I be concerned for Community♦'s mental wellbeing?

*(I would guess, though I'm not sure, that both the suggestion and the vote to reject it came from users who have since been deleted. But - if this is indeed the case - isn't there a less cryptic way to convey this information than by crediting the actions to Community♦?)*

Comment: That's a nice find. I thought community must get a bit more mature to develop such interesting behavior. Still, I am not a shrink.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The fact that the edit is attributed to Community is because it was suggested by an anonymous user.  Anonymous users' edits need to be attributed to *someone*.

As for the too minor vote, I'm reasonably confident that a user voted to reject the post and has since had their account deleted.  The vote was attributed to Community so as to have something there.

Comment: If someone chooses to edit the post, the community user will cast a vote depending on the "Suggested edit was helpful" checkbox.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn True, but if it was *actually* the Community♦ user who rejected it such as in the case you describe, it would be rejected immediately because the community user is, of course, a moderator and the rejection would not include the reason "too minor."

Comment: That's odd; why wouldn't it just show "user[numbers]" as it does on questions/answers?

Comment: @Izkata For the same reason that anonymous users aren't listed as the editor for their suggested edits.  The system needs to have a user listed with sufficient permissions to perform the given action to make sense of things.